# Backbone.js save gets '404 not found' on Slim.php

Tags: .htaccess, backbone.js, slim

I have created a Backbone.js model and want to save an instance to my MySql database.

```
var Website = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {   

                "title":"default title"
            },
    urlRoot : './websites'
});


var website = new Website();
website.save();​
```

I am using [Slim.php](http://www.slimframework.com) to create a Restful API to my database. Here is the beginning of websites\index.php:

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/websites', 'getWebsites');
$app->get('/websites/:id',  'getWebsite');
$app->post('/websites', 'addWebsite');
$app->put('/websites/:id', 'updateWebsite');
$app->delete('/websites/:id',   'deleteWebsite');

$app->run();
```

My save() triggers a POST which gets "moved permanently":

> Request
>   URL:localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone.js-mysql-reading-json/websites
>   Request Method:POST Status Code:301 Moved Permanently

Then I see a second http request sent:

> Request
>   URL:localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone.js-mysql-reading-json/websites/
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:404 Not Found

My question is: why is this request not triggering the call to the 'addWebsite' function ?
I see that the second http request is a GET, when it should be a POST, but even then there is a route for that...

I have a folder /websites/

I also set the the .htaccess and http.conf as per the [Slim routing documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/documentation/stable#routing-indepth):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

http.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone.js-mysql-reading-json/websites/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Edit**:

The call to model.save() triggers an http POST to

> localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites

.

This gets a '301 Moved Permanently' with response header says:

> localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites/

.

I assume this is due to the Slim recommended .htaccess settings.

**Question**: Is this OK to have this '301 Moved Permanently', or do I already have an issue here?

Then I see 2nd http GET to

> localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites/

---

**Update**:

I am still getting a 301 on

> localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites

, then a GET to

> localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites/

This second request works on a browser and returns

> [{"id":"1","title":"titre site 1"},{"id":"2","title":"titre site 2"}]

So that would be the response for all records, but I wanted to save 1 record.
It seems the redirect 301 is wrong.

I have a feeling it is due to Slim not finding a matching route ([Slim_Exception_RequestSlash would trigger a 301](http://dev.slimframework.com/phpdocs/classes/Slim_Exception_RequestSlash.html)).

But why my Slim script not find the route?

The request for

> localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites

is matched by:

> $app->post('/websites', function() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to orangewarp and this question:

[Why do I get a 301 redirect to folder name with slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302516/why-do-i-get-a-301-redirect-to-folder-name-with-slash)

Solution was to add `DirectorySlash Off` in the .htaccess:

My updated .htaccess (where the app calls Slim.php):

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also use SlimPHP and have a setup just like yours.

What PHP are you using? If you're using a version >= 5.3 then the way you're defining your routes would be incorrect. For a newer PHP, try this:

```
$app->get('/websites', function () {
    // your code to execute
});
```

Everything else about your setup looks pretty normal to me.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I do have PHP 5.3.5 and changed the index.php as you propose, but I still get a '404 Not Found'.

Comment: I am still at loss. Is the '301 Moved permently' normal, or do I have a problem there already?

Comment: It's strange that you're getting a 301. In your structure, `http://localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone.js-mysql-reading-json/websites/` where is your index.php file and where is your .htaccess file?

Comment: Both index.php and .htaccess are in c:/xampp/htdocs/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone.js-mysql-reading-json/websites/

Comment: That could be the problem. I have the structure `http://localhost/application/someFolder` and my index.php and .htaccess are at the the application root level. That is, `http://localhost/application/index.php` & `http://localhost/application/.htaccess` Then when I want to hit up my model urls, I just do `urlRoot: 'websites'`. The routing starts where your index and .htaccess are, then as you defined, would look for the subfolder `/websites`. Try that and get back to me on if it works. If it does, let's transfer this comment into a formal answer.

Comment: Interesting. I placed the index.php and .htaccess in the application folder, and now I get 301, then 200 on the GET request to localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites/, but receive no response. If I call localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/backbone-mysql-reading-json/websites/ in the browser I receive the json.

Comment: I am not sure I defined a 'routing'. All I have is the model with urlRoot : './websites'.

Comment: Well we're getting somewhere I think. If you are getting the JSON through your browser that's a start that means your SLIM route is at least partially working. But you say Backbone isn't getting the response... Hm. Have you looked at your response header? If you're using Google Chrome, check your Network inspector. I have a feeling your server is sending back with an "text/html" content-type header. Make sure your JSON is being sent back with a response header of content-type "application/json" for Backbone to be happy. Let's see what that does.

Comment: Yes, server is sending back 'Content-Type: text/html'. How do I change to 'application/json'? on the client side (backbone.js) or server side (index.php and Slim)?

Comment: It's a server side function. Slim has a slew of convenient helper functions that help you process your incoming requests and outgoing responses. `$response = $app->response();` `$response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';` You'll also need to revisit the documentation. I know there's a lot but it's all really useful. ;-) Keep me updated.

Comment: I have added $app->contentType('application/json');  inside my index.php and now receive a response with Response header: Content-Type:application/json. But still get an empty response when requesting from backbone client. The difference seems to be in the http request header: backbone sends 'Accept:application/json, text/javascript' and gets an empty response vs browser url bar sends 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml' and gets a response.