# Apache and Headers presence in response for Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, apache, header, cross-domain, cors

I try to figure out a cross-domain API issue.
I have an application created with Sencha Touch 2.3.1 that is using Ajax to fetch data from remote server. 
The issue that I am facing is that all Ajax requests against local server does not contain all headers in response.
On remote server, all works fine and headers are ok.

Here are two prints that show the headers sent and received for each server individualy

1 - headers sent and received from localhost (http://local.api - vhost)

Headers received:

```
Connection      Keep-Alive
Content-Length  274
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date            Mon, 07 Jul 2014 10:58:54 GMT
Keep-Alive      timeout=5, max=100
Location        http://local.api/fa/?ref.agent/lista-clienti&_dc=1404730734262
Server          Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.3
```

Headers sent:

```
Accept          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
                application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language ro-ro,ro;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,en-gb;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Content-Length  33
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host            local.api
Origin          http://sencha.local
Referer         http://sencha.local/fisa-agenti/index.html
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 
                Firefox/30.0
```

2 - headers sent and received from remote server (http://adgarage.ro)

Headers received

```
Accept-Ranges                   bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Age                             0
Connection                      keep-alive
Content-Length                  375
Content-Type                    application/json
Date                            Mon, 07 Jul 2014 10:58:52 GMT
Server                          Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 
                                OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
Via                             1.1 varnish
X-Powered-By                    PHP/5.3.13
X-Varnish                       562862498
```

Headers sent

```
Accept          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language ro-ro,ro;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,en-gb;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Host            adgarage.ro
Origin          http://sencha.local
Referer         http://sencha.local/fisa-agenti/index.html
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 
                Firefox/30.0
```

Note the `Access-Controll-Allow` header. 
It is missing from the header container received from `localhost`

And here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

this file is the same on both servers. 
I have the `headers_module` acitive on local machine.

Another thing I noticed is that response status from local is `301 moved Permanently` while the response status received from remote server is `200 Ok`

What I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified the problem. 
As discussed in this [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302516/why-do-i-get-a-301-redirect-to-folder-name-with-slash) headers were not sent because of the `301 Moved Permanently` status.

My local requests were made to `http://local.api/fa?ref.agent/...` instead of `http://local.api/fa/?ref.agent/...` - notice the trailing slash missing after `/fa` in the first link.

Everything it's ok now.